# Different proof for the inequality $b \gcd(a,c)^2+ a \gcd(b,c)^2-c \gcd(a,b)^2 \le abc$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, metric-spaces, gcd-and-lcm

In Encyclopedia of Distances, there is given a distance on natural numbers without zero:

$$d(a,b) = \log\left( \frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)^2}\right)\,.$$

Taking (again for a reference see the Encyclopedia of Distances), the Schoenberg transform of this metric we get the metric:

$$D(a,b) = 1-\exp\big(-d(a,b)\big) = 1-\frac{\gcd(a,b)^2}{ab}\,.$$

Since this metric satisfies the triangle inequality, we get:

$$D(a,b) \le D(a,c) + D(c,b)\,,$$

and the inequality, after some algebra,
$$b \gcd(a,c)^2+ a \gcd(b,c)^2-c \gcd(a,b)^2 \le abc$$
follows for three natural numbers $a,b,c$.
My question is, if there is a more direct proof for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be the g.c.d. of $a,b$ and $c$.

Let $ RU$ be the g.c.d. of $a$ and $b$,  let $SU$ be the g.c.d. of $a$ and $c$, let $TU$ be the g.c.d. of $b$ and $c$.

Then there are natural numbers  $A,B$ and $C$, such that $a=RSUA,b=RTUB,c=STUC.$

The inequality to be proved then becomes the rather obvious one

$$SB+TA-RC\le RSTABC.$$

Comment: I am not convinced that if $\gcd(a,b)=RU$, $\gcd(b,c)=TU$, and $\gcd(c,a)=SU$, then $a=RSU$, $b=RTU$, and $c=STU$.  Take $a=b=1$ and $c=2$.  What would be true is that $a=RSUX$, $b=RTUY$, and $c=STUZ$ for some extra $X,Y,Z$ with more conditions.

Comment: I checked your claim, and _if_ $a=RSU,b=RTU,c=STU$ then you are right, however I can not see why $a,b,c$ must be of the given form.

Comment: @WE Tutorial School is correct - I omitted the X,Y,Z.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I checked it and it seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$abc-b\gcd(a,c)^2-a\gcd(b,c)^2=c\left(a-\frac{\gcd(a,c)^2}{c}\right)\left(b-\frac{\gcd(b,c)^2}{c}\right)-\frac{\gcd(a,c)^2\gcd(b,c)^2}{c}.$$
Since $ac\ge\gcd(a,c)^2$ and $bc\ge\gcd(b,c)^2$, we see that
$$abc-b\gcd(a,c)^2-a\gcd(b,c)^2\ge-\frac{\gcd(a,c)^2\gcd(b,c)^2}{c}.$$
We only need to show that
$$\frac{\gcd(a,c)^2\gcd(b,c)^2}{c}\leq c\gcd(a,b)^2.$$
But this is equivalent to
$$\gcd(a,c)\gcd(b,c)\leq c\gcd(a,b).$$
However, this follows from
$$\gcd(xy,mn)\geq \gcd(x,m)\gcd(y,n)$$
by taking $x=a$, $y=c$, $m=c$, and $n=b$.  From this proof, we can also see that the inequality $$b\gcd(a,c)^2+a\gcd(b,c)^2-c\gcd(a,b)^2\leq abc$$ is an equality iff $a=c$ or $b=c$.

Comment: Your inequality before we need only is not justified.

Comment: The very first equation I wrote was to justify the inequality between "we see that" and "We only need to show that...".